# Tomcat 8.5 anti-CSRF nonce not being generated

Tags: java, tomcat, csrf, csrf-protection, nonce

I have a web application that runs on Tomcat 8.5. I would like to update the application to rely on Tomcats native anti-CSRF tokens to protect key POST requests on the web app. I have done quite of bit of researched and followed a number of example yet I still cannot seem to get this to work.

web.xml:

```
<filter>
    <filter-name>CSRFPreventionFilter</filter-name>
    <filter-class> org.apache.catalina.filters.CsrfPreventionFilter </filter-class>
    <init-param>
        <param-name>entryPoints</param-name>
        <param-value>appNameRemoved/login.jsp</param-value>
    </init-param>
</filter>

<filter-mapping>
    <filter-name>CSRFPreventionFilter</filter-name>
    <url-pattern>/appNameRemoved/folder1/*</url-pattern>
</filter-mapping>
```

So at face value this appears to work. Any attempt to access a URL inside of folder1 is denied with a 403 (good). The issue arises when I try to generate the nonce value to allow authorized parties to access the privileaged area.

In my main.jsp (JSP opened after logging in on entry-point login.jsp), I have the following Java code to try to generate the nonce value:

```
String antiCSRF = response.encodeURL("/appNameRemoved/folder1/delete");
```

The issue is, the value generated is simply

```
"/appNameRemoved/folder1/delete"
```

rather than an expected URL (as seen by other peoples examles) such as:

```
"/appNameRemoved/folder1/delete?org.apache.catalina.filters.CSRF_NONCE=CB5C65E1D87A39D5557D6BCBC24E54A9"
```

Hence my question, why is response.encodeURL() not actually encoding the URL with the nonce value even though as far as I can see, the filter is setup correctly and checking for nonce's when accessing the privileged URL's.

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It seems you have kept your `main.jsp` (in which you are using `response.encodeURL()`) out side the folder `/appNameRemoved/folder1/`.

By using

```
<filter-mapping>
    <filter-name>CSRFPreventionFilter</filter-name>
    <url-pattern>/appNameRemoved/folder1/*</url-pattern>
</filter-mapping>
```

you are applying `CSRFPreventionFilter` to urls `/appNameRemoved/folder1/*`. i.e. all the urls with pattern `/appNameRemoved/folder1/*` will be protected with CSRF nonce.

By applying

```
<init-param>
   <param-name>entryPoints</param-name>
   <param-value>url1, url2</param-value>
</init-param>
```

you are saying tomcat that out of `/appNameRemoved/folder1/*`, url1 and url2 are allowed even without CSRF nonce.

Now what you have done is

1. You have put `appNameRemoved/login.jsp` as entry point which you do not need to do that because it is anyway accessible as it is outside `/appNameRemoved/folder1/*` urls.
2. Perhaps your `main.jsp` in which you are using `response.encodeURL("/appNameRemoved/folder1/delete")`, is also out side `/appNameRemoved/folder1/*`. CSRF nounce will only be generated in the resources on which `CSRFPreventionFilter` is applied. Had your `main.jsp` been placed in folder `/appNameRemoved/folder1/`, proper CSRF nonce would have been added to the encoded url. Again in such case, to make `main.jsp` accessible, you would need to set it as entryPoint in your init prams

Like this

```
<init-param>
   <param-name>entryPoints</param-name>
   <param-value>appNameRemoved/folder1/main.jsp</param-value>
</init-param>
```

Comment: @dFrancisco - Welcome! Glad to see it actually helped.